# ANTLR correct grammar for if statement

Tags: antlr, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I have created a simple grammar for a language I have decided to call SWL:

```
grammar swl;

program   : 'begin' statement+ 'end';

statement : assign | add | sub | mul | div | print | whilecond | ifcond ;
condition : expr ;
expr      : '(' expr ')' | expr 'and' expr | expr 'or' expr | 'not' expr | expr '=' expr | expr '>=' expr | expr '<=' expr | expr '>' expr | expr '<' expr | ID | NUMBER;

assign    : 'let' ID 'be' (NUMBER | ID) ;
print     : 'print' (NUMBER | ID) ;

add       : 'add' (NUMBER | ID) 'to' ID ;
sub       : 'sub' (NUMBER | ID) 'to' ID ;
mul       : 'mul' (NUMBER | ID) 'to' ID ;
div       : 'div' (NUMBER | ID) 'to' ID ;

whilecond : 'while (' condition ') do' statement+ 'stop' ;

ifcond    : 'if (' condition ') then' statement+ 'stop' | 'if (' condition ') then' statement+ 'else' statement+ 'stop' ;

ID        : [a-z]+ ;
NUMBER    : [0-9]+ ;
WS        : [ \n\t]+ -> skip;
ErrorChar : . ;
```

I am a bit in trouble with the `ifcond`. Given this SWL program:

```
begin
    if (not(a > 1) or (c <= b)) then
     mul 5 to k
    stop
end
```

I am able to get this C++ output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    if ( !(a>1) || (c<=b)) {
    k *= 5;
    }
}
```

This is great! By the way with the following input:

```
begin
    if (not(a > 1) or (c <= b)) then
     mul 5 to k
    else
     mul 15 to k
    stop
end
```

I have this output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    if ( !(a>1) || (c<=b)) {
    k *= 5;
    k *= 15;
    }
}
```

As you can see the second example is missing the else `statement` part. What is wrong? Do I have to change the `ifcond` grammar and add another rule/variable? This is the `MyListner.cpp` file.

```cpp
void fixString(string& cond) {

    size_t pos = cond.find("and", 0);
    if (pos != string::npos) { cond.replace(pos, 3, " && "); }

    pos = cond.find("or", 0);
    if (pos != string::npos) { cond.replace(pos, 2, " || "); }

    pos = cond.find("not", 0);
    if (pos != string::npos) { cond.replace(pos, 3, " !"); }

}

void MyListener::enterIfcond(swlParser::IfcondContext *ctx) {
    string cond = ctx->condition()->getText();
    fixString(cond);

    cout << string(indent, ' ') << "if (" << cond << ") {" << endl;
}

void MyListener::exitIfcond(swlParser::IfcondContext *ctx) {
    cout << string(indent, ' ') << "}" << endl;
}
```

My suspect is that the grammar is not good enough and I'd need another variable to call the else part. I don't know how to fix this issue, any idea?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your listener, not in the grammar.

Comment: It's unusual to have spaces inside tokens, like in `') then'`. That means that there must be exactly one space between `)` and `then`. If you write `')' 'then'` instead, it could be 0 or more spaces or, for example, a newline, which is way more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The `ifcond` is fine but it would be easier if you added another variable before the else so that you can use the `exit` method of the listener. Use this:

```
ifelsecond: ifcond | statement ;
ifcond    : 'if (' condition ') then' statement+ 'stop' | 'if (' condition ') then' ifelsecond+ 'else' statement+ 'stop' ;
```

Now you can easily edit `MyListner.cpp` like this:

```
void MyListener::enterIfcond(swlParser::IfcondContext *ctx) {
    string cond = ctx->condition()->getText();
    fixString(cond);

    cout << "\n" << string(indent, ' ') << "if (" << cond << ") {" << endl;
}

void MyListener::exitIfcond(swlParser::IfcondContext *ctx) {
    cout << string(indent, ' ') << "}\n" << endl;
}

void MyListener::exitIfelsecond(swlParser::IfelsecondContext *ctx) {
    cout << string(indent, ' ') << "} else {" << endl;
}
```

You grammar is good but you are using a not really needed production that makes the listener code harder to write. Since you are using the `stop` you don't have the [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) issue.

The solution I have given may not be the best but it works because the grammar is not ambiguous because of the "scoped" statements that are enclosed inside something (in your case `then` and `stop`).